# CSS 2D Transform Matrix decimal place limits

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

Perhaps this is an unusual way to do things, but I am creating an interactive map that has landmark markers embedded in the actual map image (a colored circle with a number inside of it). The image is in a div that allows you to pan and zoom with you mouse and mousewheel. I am using CSS transforms to accomplish that pan and zoom. This part is working great.

The issue is that I have 90 landmarks on the map that need to be able to have the user click on them and have a tooltip/popup open with more info. I am accomplishing this with an image map and specifying the coordinates. That is all working as well.

However, I want the user to be able to hover over the image map area and have an alternate image display over the top of the main map image to effectively "highlight" the landmark circle on hover. Then I use the same alternate image when they click on the landmark to show a "highlighted" circle for the selected landmark.

I have this working by using a single div for the hover image display, moving it off canvas and then applying a CSS transform to move it into place and show the right background image when the user hovers over the image map area.

This is all working except for one very teeny tiny problem:

I am passing in transform values to the CSS through jQuery and they are being rounded to 3 decimal places when the transform is applied. Here is javascript used to set an example transform.

```html
$(function(){
 $('#landmarkHighlightSelected').css({
 'transform-origin': '0px 0px 0px',
 'transform': 'translate(121.11172485351563px, 335.38427734375000px) scale(1)', 
 });  
});
```

When I inspect the transform in Chrome dev tools, I see that the translate values have been converted to 3 decimal places (rounding applied). The matrix value is listed as the following:

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 112.112, 335.384)
```

Under "normal" circumstances, this likely wouldn't matter. But the effect that I am getting is that the "highlight" div that is moved into place is "close" to where it should be, but depending on what the results are of the calculation taking into account image pan/zoom values, I will get a "shift" effect and you can see that the "highlight" div is offset ever so slightly from the landmark in the resized/moved map image behind it.

So what I am seeing is that the CSS transforms are limited to 3 decimal places? Is that right? Is there any way to get them to accept more decimal places?

I understand that what I am doing is a bit unorthodox and that by embedding the "off" state landmark markers in the map image, it's allowing the pan and zoom to move the landmark to values that the browser appears not to be able to render.

But I went with this approach because trying to move 90 divs around in the browser allowing pan and zoom in case the user moused over it was causing a huge jerking/dragging/delayed response in the movement because the code was trying to recalculate the positions of all of those divs as the user moved things around.

Any help or insight on this would be SO SO SO appreciated it. I have been getting nowhere on this for over a week and just figured out that it was the 3 decimal place limit causing the rendered div to appear to shift.

Thank you so much,
Jenny

Comment: I'm not sure that rounding is your problem here, you're talking about a difference of 1/1,000th of a pixel. Have you double checked your calculations to make sure they're correct? Maybe there's a phantom padding or margin throwing things off?